# How to edit a earlier line from the line that was originally searched in gvim editor

Tags: vim, grep

Say there  are two lines like

```
1:Could be anything

2:FOO is a word
```

Now I want edit the #1 line by searching `/FOO` using `:%s`, or I want to add a new line above the line which has FOO in it.

Answer (score 3):

[`:help :global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global) is your friend.

This command:

```
:g/FOO/-2s/any/some
```

would turn:

```
1:Could be anything

2:FOO is a word
```

into:

```
1:Could be something

2:FOO is a word
```

And this command:

```
:g/FOO/normal! O
```

would turn:

```
1:Could be something

2:FOO is a word
```

into:

```
1:Could be something


2:FOO is a word
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have tried `:g/FOO/-2d/any/some` but it is showing E488 error

Comment: It worked, I should figured it out by myself anyway thanks a lot. It will help me not to go for a script but I can replace sentences direct from gvim. Thanks again :)